# execute JDBC query in EJB3 stateless bean

Tags: jdbc, ejb-3.0, facade

I am using the following pattern for my service **EJB3** stateless beans. Basically, each database table is exposed through a **DAO / facade** type class (itself also a stateless **EJB3** bean).

My hypothetical *AService* bean is then injected with the facades of the various database tables it needs to use. However, certain more complex logic or logic is not provided in the facades (which are used exlusively for CRUD-type operations on one table). For this reason, I am also directly injecting the **DataSource** so I can use **JDBC** for the more complex queries.

Are there any glaring or subtle anti-patterns / caveats in my approach?

```
 @Stateless
 @Local (IAService.ILocal.class)
 @Remote(IAService.IRemote.class)
 public class AService implements IAService.ILocal, IAService.IRemote{

     @PersistenceContext(unitName = "cashflowPU")
     private EntityManager em;

    // inject CRUD facades for straightforward operations
    @EJB
    private ITableAFacade.ILocal tgAFacade;
    ...

    // inject the data source for non-straightforward operations that require JDBC
    @Resource(mappedName="java:/cashflow") DataSource dataSource;


    public BigDecimal methodThatNeedsComplexQuery (...params) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        BigDecimal retValue = null;
        try {
             conn = dataSource.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement pstm = ...
             ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery(); ...
             while (rs.next()) ...
        } finally {
             conn.close();
             return retValue;
        }
    }                                                      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use EntityMangaer.createNativeQuery(String sqlString) instead of injecting a datasource.